# NHibernate and interfaces with different implementations

Tags: c#, nhibernate, class-structure

I have recently started working with C# and NHibernate so all this is quite novice to me.

In the application I'm building I need to calculate distances between UK postcodes. 
One of the approaches is to use grid reference and Pythagoras distance.
Another approach is to use Google Maps to get distances.

I have an interface `Ipostcode` with method `getDistance(IPostcode p)`
and depending on implementations classes will be talking to different tables.

For Grid References I'll have GridRefPostcode object and DB table: (string)postcode, (long)northing, (long)easting.

For Google Maps I'll GoogleMapsPostcode object and DB table: (string)postcode, (string)otherPostcode, (double)distance.

Class Person will have a field `IPostcode`, and then I'll be calculating distances based on `getDistance()` provided by both classes.

Now the question is: How to map this class-relationship in NHibernate? How I can fit interface into mapping?

```
                   Person
                      ^
                      |
                  IPostcode ( Interface )
                   ^     ^
                   |     |
      GridRefPostcode    GoogleMapsPostcode
```

Is it even possible? I have a gut feeling that my class structure needs to be changed completely, but this seems to be the most reasonable solution: If I have distance between 2 postcodes provided by Google, I use it, if it is not available, I step down to GridReferences.

Any ideas are highly appreciated!